# Creating something like 'ol' (ordered list) in Polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0, riot.js

I am very new to [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org), and I was looking on how I could create something like 'my own version of an ordered list'.

*(BTW I am also looking at [riotjs](http://riotjs.com/) and trying to do something similar there, just to get an understanding of how it works, so if you know something about riotjs, don't hesitate to post an answer too)*

My html would look something like this:

```
<my-ol>
  <my-li>My first list item inside my ol</my-li>
  <my-li>My second list item inside my ol</my-li>
</my-ol>
```

and I would produce 2 dom-modules similar to:

```
<dom-module id="my-ol">
  <template>
    <style>
      ...
    </style>
    <div class="myol">
      <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer( { ... } );
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="my-li">
  <template>
    <div class="myli">
      <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer( { ... } );
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

That all works, but if I would really want to make it work like the 'native' ol, I should be able to add the number of the item to the output.

Does anyone know if that is possible, and if so, how?

*(My ultimate goal would be to get that working - well not an exact copy of ol of course, that is just an example that bears enough similarities to what I want to do - and then make the individual list items contentEditable, and make sure I can get that content back somehow, but first things first)*

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the solution in Riot.](https://jsfiddle.net/6a9u2oux/2/)

```
<my-ol>
  <yield />

  this.count = this.opts.count || 0
</my-ol>

<my-li>
  <div>{index}. <yield/></div>

  this.index = ++this.parent.count
</my-li>
```

Riot tags are very easy to understand. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it does show the item number and it is `contenteditable`.

Comment: :) of course, when you use the li element again, it will show the number, because that's already implemented by the browser. Now if I would like to write similar behaviour myself, I would need some way to figure out the item index (and have it available in javascript so that I can decide if I want it renedered a 1,2,3 or a,b,c or i, ii, iii or with icons or ...). 

I am trying to understand if the concept is powerful enough so that I could fully rewrite existing html elements completely. If I cannot do that, it is still crippled in some way.

Comment: That was easy :) Since my 'main' question was about Polymer, I'll not yet mark this question as resolved, but thanks for the Riot version.

Comment: I also made it so you could pick the first index. `<my-ol count="5">` would start the list at 5.